# Why/how is locale set to "en" despite "de" in application.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

`cookies[:locale]` in my view outputs `en`.

How is this possible when I have `config.i18n.default_locale = "de"` in `application.rb` (with restarted server)?

`locale` is neither set in `routes`, `ApplicationController` nor the current actionpack.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know [`rails-i18n`](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) doesn't changes or manipulates cookie values. It is even [*frowned upon*](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-and-passing-the-locale) to use cookies to pass local values over sessions:

> You may be tempted to store the chosen locale in a session or a
>   cookie. However, do not do this. The locale should be transparent and
>   a part of the URL. This way you won't break people's basic assumptions
>   about the web itself: if you send a URL to a friend, they should see
>   the same page and content as you. A fancy word for this would be that
>   you're being RESTful.

If you want to check what locale is currently set call [`I18n.locale`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#the-public-i18n-api) in your view or controller.